# How to read a profiler .hprof memory heap dump in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, memory, heap-memory, profiler

I am in desperate search of a memory leak and I was wondering how to read my memory heap dump:

[image]

[image]

- Does that for example mean, that `MainActivity` is active twice? Or only that it's in the backstack twice?
- Why would my `TrackingService` be called twice? It gets activated at startup and then basically forgotten by the rest of the app.
- What's up with `ChooseLoginRegistrationActivity`? Is it in the backstack 3 or 5 times? What are the two weird `Lambda` activity? `ChooseLoginRegistrationActivity` is always finished with `finish()` after a ´startActivity()`, should it even pop up here at all?
- When I call `finish()` on an activity, will the memory allocated to that activity be freed up with the next iteration of the `garbage collector`? Because when I call the `gc` manually in the `profiler`, the memory wasn't released, and waiting didn't help either. Going to the desktop of my smartphone released like 50% of my apps memory, and going back to the app didn't claim the memory back.

Comment: DemoClass$... means there is a class inside DemoClass

Comment: So "TrackingService" and "TrackingService$1" means what? That my Tracking Service runs twice, once with a inner class? There is no class inside my service.

Comment: No. "TrackingService" and "TrackingService$1" means there is a Class `TrackingService` and another Class `TrackingService$1` which is a annonymous class inside `TrackingService`

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but you may find using [Eclipse MAT](https://wiki.eclipse.org/MemoryAnalyzer) useful. You can create a heap dump from Android Studio Profiler and convert it into standard `.hprof` in order to import it into Eclipse MAT.

In **Android\Sdk\platform-tools** (to have access to the `hprof-conv` tool available that converts the dump), open a terminal and type the command

```
hprof-conv AS-name.hprof EclipseMAT-name.hprof
```

This will generate a converted file with your given *EclipseMAT-name* name which you can use to import a proper standard heap dump into Eclipse MAT.
After importing into MAT you can see an overview of your memory at the given heap and can even get custom reports for Leak Suspects which may bring you closer to the culprits of those terrifying OOM errors.

[LeakCanary](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/fundamentals/) can also prove useful for finding these pesky errors.

Hope this might help you and anyone else with finding memory errors.